# Getting element from DOM - Angular 4

Tags: angular, devexpress

I need to get an element from DOM and add style to it (background color). I cannot use ViewChild with #someId on that element, because the element is not in my html, it renders once I open a popup. The class of that element is 'dx-popup-content'. I tried with  but cant do it, can't do it with `this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('dx-popup-content')` because target element is not in the native element (in this case, dx-scheduler). I am using DevExpress in case that is important.

Basically, I want to select it and change the style inside my function:

```
openTooltip(event) {
    // event.cancel = true;
    this.prepareTooltipData(event.appointmentData);
  }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What event is the openTooltip handler for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious : how is that not in your HTML ? Are you using a library, making a pop-up on the fly ... ?

Anyways, if you **really** can't use ViewChild, you still can use vanilla JS :

```
let popup = document.getElementById('dx-popup-content');
```

I recommend you use an ID, and not a class, to be sure to get the correct element.

Comment: This is not recommended. see #2 http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

Comment: Thanks! I use devexpress and it renders the html of dropdowns after you click on on inputs for example. How can I add class to this element though, or style?

Comment: Don't give me an angularJs blog please. This is Angular. And is your html in an html template, or are you creating it on the fly ?

Comment: I'd recommend Renderer 2. You could then do this.renderer.setStyle(). See https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2

Comment: It's not an angularjs blog, If you would have clicked it, you would have seen that.

Comment: To add class or style, just do it once you got the element with vanilla JS, with style or className properties

Comment: This is in the URL, my bad. And anyways, this still is a blog, not an official documentation. This is opinion based (and I'm on phone in the cold, the less moves I do the better :D)

Answer (score 1):

you could always use `document`:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('dx-popup-content');
```

Comment: This is not recommended. See #2 http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html